# How to reset Magic Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have the latest Magic Keyboard (the one with a switch, not a button) and a 2018 iMac.

Today after lunch, the keyboard Magically stopped doing anything. Here's what I checked:

- Battery was not low, I charged it yesterday and checked the batter was full yesterday.
- Keyboard worked fine before lunch.
- No coffee spill.
- No kids or other bad actors in the room.
- Tried plugging in and unplugging the charging cable.
- Tried changing the charging cable to a different port on the iMac.

Afraid to restart because then I can't type in the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reset your keyboard:

> Hold down the Shift and Option keys ('Alt' on some keyboards) and at the same time click on the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. Once the menu is showing, release the keys. From the Bluetooth menu, choose Debug > Remove All Devices. Reboot your Mac, then setup your keyboard and/or mouse as normal.

- http://davemeehan.com/technology/how-to-reset-an-apple-wireless-bluetooth-keyboard-mouse-or-trackpad

Comment: This reset the bluethoot pairing on the computer. It does not reset the peripheral (keyboard and mouse)

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below instructions to reconnect the bluetooth keyboard (one having the switch) if the keyboard stops working:

If your device has a built-in battery, you can use a USB-C to Lightning Cable or a Lightning to USB Cable to connect and pair it with your Mac. After you connect the device to your Mac with the cable, turn on the device and make sure the power switch is green. When you disconnect the cable, your device will be paired with your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is close. Shift + Option while clicking the bluetooth icon in the menubar brings up the debug options. You want to select  `Factory reset all connected Apple devices`:

[image: Screenshot of bluetooth menu debug options, with the correct 'Factory Reset all connected Apple Devices' option selected]

Comment: No debug options anymore, it seems.